# not deleting cookie (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nshttpcookie

```
        NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

        NSArray *cookies = [storage cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/"]];
        NSLog(@"old cookies!: %@",cookies);
        NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
        for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
        NSLog(@"new cookies!: %@",cookies);
```

I am trying to delete the facebook cookie in a logout function but no cookies are deleted.  I do not understand why.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: whoops solved my own problem: It doesn't delete the cookie, it deletes it from NSHTTPCookieStorage so if you re- call 
cookies = [storage cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/"]];
then it will work

Comment: Can you elaborate your solution please, as I have the same problem with facebook cookies. When I logout, remove all cookies, and then restart the app it still remembers all of the cookies and so retains the login info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your changes to the NSHTTPCookieStorage to be retained, you'll also want to synchronize standardUserDefaults after modifying the cookie store:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To prevent this from slowing down your app, you may also want to call this on a background thread like so:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    //TODO: Cookie deletion logic here
});
```

EDIT:

If you just need to disregard cookies altogether for a given NSURLRequest, you can do so with:

```
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
```

Where request is your instance of NSURLRequest.